# How to get merge commits to master?

Tags: git, merge

**TL;DR**: How do I find only those merge commits, that merge into a specific branch?

---

I have roughly this commit history:

```
        f → g → - - - - k → l → m           [m] ← feature/2
       /               /         \
      /               /           \
     /               /             \
a → b → - - - - - - h → - - - - n → o       [o] ← master
     \             / \         /
      \           /   \       /
       \         /     \     /              [e] ← feature/1
        c → d → e       i → j               [j] ← feature/3
```

- `a` - initial commit in `master`
- `h` - merge commit from `feature/1` to `master`
- `k` - merge commit from `master` to `feature/2`
- `n` - merge commit from `feature/3` to `master`
- `o` - merge commit from `feature/2` to `master`

Currently, all commits are in `master`, and all branches except for `master` are gone (`push -d`).

I'm trying to find only those merge commits that are directed towards `master`; these are `h`, `n`, and `o`. The commit `k` is not included because it goes *from* master.

I'm trying this command:

```
git rev-list a..o --merges
```

… but it returns all four merge commits, including `k`.

How do I find only "merge to `master`" commits? Ideally, this shouldn't involve parsing commit messages, since those can be changed before the merge (at least, in GitHub).

Comment: @wnoise: your comment about the DAG is globally correct, but git stores an extra information in merge commits : the parents are actually ordered, and the first parent is always "the previous head of the branch". `--first-parent` is generally a good way to track what happened on a branch (note : "generally", not "always")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the [`--first-parent`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#Documentation/git-rev-list.txt---first-parent) option :

```sh
git rev-list --first-parent --merges master
# or :
git rev-list --first-parent --merges a..o
```

---

If your `master` branch can only be updated through merge requests, this will actually always work.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! If you don't mind, I've edited the answer to add link to the docs

Comment: This example returns many commits that are not merges from a branch, into master.

Comment: @Mort: git doesn't have a true notion of branch, the closest thing to it is that "first parent" sequence. There may be some actions in the history of your master branch (for example: first merge master into develop, then inadvertently _fast forward_ master to develop when you try to merge develop into master) which leads to a sequence of first parents which doesn't match what you would call "that's the master branch". Please inspect your history, and check how it is laid out.

Comment: @LeGEC: I agree, but I feel it's important for future readers of this issue to understand that your answer, although marked as an answer, does not actually provide a solution to the question _How do I find only those merge commits, that merge into a specific branch?_. Letting others know why your answer might not  work for them, prevents them from spending time troubleshooting the accepted answer.